# ActiveMQ Duplicate Message Detection (Wildfly, Java EE)

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-artemis

First, sorry for my english!
I have a project with JMS and ActiveMQ

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Producer {

public void produceMessage(List<String> entityIds) {
  try {
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:/JmsXA");
    Destination destination = (Destination) initialContext.lookup("jms/queue/cachedAttrs");

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

    entityIds.forEach(entityId -> {                 
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(entityId);
                message.setStringProperty("_AMQ_DUPL_ID", entityId);
                producer.send(message);                     
        }
    );

    connection.close();
    session.close();
    initialContext.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("..." + e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}

@MessageDriven(
  name = "Consumer",
  activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = 
"jms/queue/cachedAttrs"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = 
  "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useDLQ", propertyValue = "false")
  }
)
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {  

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
  TextMessage id = (TextMessage) message;
}
}
```

Producer.produceMessage() may call in many places of project and in same time. I need check duplicate ID and not call Consumer for ID, if this ID contains in queue.

I read https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html
and do this

```
message.setStringProperty("_AMQ_DUPL_ID", entityId);
```

Calling Producer:

```
producer.produceMessage(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "1", "3", "2"));
```

And getting exception:

> Caused by: ActiveMQDuplicateIdException[errorType=DUPLICATE_ID_REJECTED 
>       message=Duplicate message detected - message will not be routed. Message information:ServerMessage[messageID=266288062339,durable=true,userID=0c03aadc-c07a-11e8-9fb7-775c9c2bdfeb,priority=4, bodySize=225, timestamp=Tue Sep 25 11:18:25 GMT+07:00 2018,expiration=0, durable=true, address=jms.queue.deviceCachedAttrs,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=f627a880-c079-11e8-9fb7-775c9c2bdfeb,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=1]]@1895765804]
>   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:406)
>   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:304)
>   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.xaPrepare(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:457)
>   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.prepare(ClientSessionImpl.java:1241)

What i do wrong?
And can i @Inject my Producer in service or i need create new object?
Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you've done nothing wrong.  Based on what you've said you need the broker to reject duplicate messages.  You've set the duplicate ID in the message and the broker has detected a duplicate message which it has rejected.  Notice the exception says, "Duplicate message detected - message will not be routed."

Comment: If you believe this answer is correct please mark it as such so it's clear to any future users who may have the same question.

Comment: I have a problem. Where i can catch this exception (ActiveMQDuplicateIdException) in my code? In stacktrace this exception throw in native activeMq classes. My code can't catch it

Comment: The `ActiveMQDuplicateIdException` is in the "Caused by" clause of the stack-trace.  There should be a parent exception that you can catch.  Since `prepare()` is being invoked my guess is that an `javax.transaction.xa.XAException` is being thrown which you can catch.  You'd need to provide the full stack-trace to know for sure.